# Playing shoutcast live radio url in samsung phones

Tags: android, shoutcast

I am building an app that playing live radio stream using android mediaplayer class(not using open source nagare project). The stream is playing fine in emulator and g1 phone. But when I tested the app on my samsung galaxy i9003 phone it did not work and it throws exception prepare called in wrong state. Do samsung phone have trouble playing live radio url. If anybody have experience playing live radio stream using mediaplayer please give your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default android does not support m3u formats with URL. So, it needs to be implemented explicitly. may be in G1 it is implemented. In any case the codec used in case of Samsung is samsung specific and different from the one used in G1, so can be some issue with their codec. Can you share your code with me? I will try to fix the problem.

Comment: The code is just simple setting datasource and calling start.
MediaPlayer mp  = new MediaPlayer(); 
mp.setDataSource("http://ip:port");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
I read somewhere that for live radio streeaming is possible only in some phones that has os version greater that or equal to 2.2. Also I think for live radio url you have to download in chunks and play those small files and playing directly from live radio url is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app for playing radio stream (tried with shoutcast) using android MediaPlayer class and tested the application on samsung nesus. It is working fine for me. So, may be there is some issue with your code where you are doing playlist parsing. You can just have a relook into the parsing code.